# Alamofire - error converting from Swift 2 to swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, nserror

I'm converting my project from `Swift 2.3` to `Swift 3.0`. We are using the Alamofire pod for networking. Now I'm facing a issue with `NSError`.

When we write `error: responseObj.result.error`, Swift 3 is not accepting this. Help me to solve this problem.

Check my code:

```
static func getDataFromAPI(parameters : [String : AnyObject], successCallBack : @escaping APISuccessCallBack, failureCallBack : @escaping APIFailureCallBack) {

        client.makePOSTRequest(service: Constants.API_BASE_URL, parameters: parameters) { (statusCode, response, error) -> () in
            if statusCode == MobomoAPIClient.HTTPStatusCode.Success {
                successCallBack(response)
            }
            else {

                failureCallBack(client.responseErrorMessage(statusCode: statusCode, response: response, error: error))
            }
        }
    }


typealias APIClientResponseCallBack = (_ statusCode: Int?, _ response : AnyObject?, _ error : NSError?) -> ()

`self.alamoFireManager!.request(urlString, method: method, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers)
            .responseJSON { (responseObj) -> Void in
                responseCallBack(statusCode: responseObj.response?.statusCode, response: responseObj.result.value as AnyObject, error: responseObj.result.error)
        }`
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change the callback's `NSError?` to `Error?` and cast the failureCallBack's error to `Error`.

```
typealias APIClientResponseCallBack = (_ statusCode: Int?, _ response : AnyObject?, _ error : Error?) -> ()
```

---

```
failureCallBack(client.responseErrorMessage(statusCode: statusCode, response: response, error: error as Error))
```

Comment: any change in the
failureCallBack(client.responseErrorMessage(statusCode: statusCode, response: response, error: error))

because when we change in the typealias APIClientResponseCallBack then error occurred in the failureCallBack error: error

Comment: cannot invoke 'responseCallBack' with argument list of type '(statusCode: Int?, response : AnyObject?, error : Error?)'

facing this issue